# How to add a background color for an Android app through Theme?

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I created a theme and applied this through AndroidManifest.xml

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#8BC34A</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#689F38</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#8BC34A</item>
    </style>
```

This works good

But when I add options for color:Background
I get an error:

Error:(1468, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorBackground'.

When I double tap the error , it directs to Values.xml

How to add a Background color through theme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code...

First define the color:

```
<color name="background">#FF0000 </color>
```

Create a style/theme that references to that color:

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"> 
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
 </style>
```

Apply this theme in your activities in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one in your `MyTheme` style.

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
```

There is a theme editor built-in Android Studio, when style.xml is opened, you will see Open editor text at Top Right corner click on that. Makes extremely easy to customize themes.